# Как обработать исключение при десериализации в c# если заведомо загружается файл в неверном формате

Tags: c#, wpf

прошу помощи. В c# новичок, делаю лабораторную работу, один из пунктов сериализация и десериализация объектов. В своем проекте использую механизм бинарной сериализации. Но при проверке преподаватель делает десериализацию заведомо неверно файла, соответственно появляется необработанное исключение или программа просто зависает.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно обработать это исключение или недесериализовывать объекты, которые не подходят по формату.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Сериализация объекта
        /// </summary>
        private void SerializeOjectButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = 
                new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = "Document";
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".dat";
            dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.dat)|*.dat";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string fileName = dlg.FileName;
            }

            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream
                (dlg.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                formatter.Serialize(fs, actionList);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Десериализация объекта
        /// </summary>
        private void DeerializeObjectButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = 
                new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".dat";
            dlg.Filter = ".dat|*.dat*";
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string fileName = dlg.FileName;
            }

            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(dlg.FileName,
                FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                //if ()
                //{ };
                List<Actions> deserializeActions = 
                    (List<Actions>)formatter.Deserialize(fs);

                actionList = deserializeActions;

                actionGrid.ItemsSource = actionList;

                actionGrid.Items.Refresh();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Загрузка данных выполнена");
        }
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? Про конструкцию `try-catch` не знаете?

Comment: Там есть `CanDeserialize`  метод. Try-catch - спорный вариант.

Comment: Про `try-catch` знаю, но не знаю как применить его в данном случае. Сейчас почитаю про метод `CanDeserialize` спасибо за совет.

Comment: У `BinaryFormatter` нету `CanDeserialize` (он у xml) прийдётся через `try-catch` выкручиваться.... наверное...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

к классу который будем сериализовать добавляем

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeItem
{}
```

Враппер на сериализацию:

```
public static class Serializator
{
    private static BinaryFormatter _bin = new BinaryFormatter();

    public static void Serialize(string pathOrFileName, object objToSerialise)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(pathOrFileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            try 
            {
                _bin.Serialize(stream, objToSerialise);
            }
            catch (SerializationException e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string pathOrFileName) 
    {
        T items;

        using (Stream stream = File.Open(pathOrFileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            try 
            {
                items = (T) _bin.Deserialize(stream);
            }
            catch (SerializationException e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

ну и, собственно, сам пример использования:

```
List<SomeItem> itemsCollected;//list with some data

Serializator.Serialize("data.dat", itemsCollected);

var a = Serializator.Deserialize<List<SomeItem>>("data.dat");
```

В случае ошибки будет выдавать в консоль сообщение о исключении сериализации. Т.к. у тебя не консольная апликуха, нужно будет подправить вывод ошибки в консоль на какой-нибудь ShowMessage();

PS: препод не поверит что это ты написал. Перепиши другим способом код.

---

Так же пример обработки ошибок при сериализации можно найти здесь:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.deserialize?view=netframework-4.7.2